# Trying to create mikroConfig to MikroORM with typescript and i got this error message

Tags: typescript, mikro-orm

i'm studying TS and building a microconfig file like:

```
import { __prod__ } from './constants'
import {  Options, MikroORM } from '@mikro-orm/core'
import path from 'path'

const config: Options = {
  migrations: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './migrations'),
    pattern: /^[\w-]+\d+\.[tj]s$/,
  },
  entities: [Post],
  dbName: 'lireddit',
  user: 'postgres',
  password: 'StrongPassword',
  type: 'postgresql',
  debug: !__prod__,
} as Parameters<typeof MikroORM.init>[0];

export default config;
```

when i try to compile the console gives me this:
`src/mikro-orm.config.ts:6:7 - error TS2322: Type 'Options<IDatabaseDriver<Connection>> | Configuration<IDatabaseDriver<Connection>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Options<IDatabaseDriver<Connection>>'.`

Trying to create mikroConfig file to MikroORM with typescript and i got this error message, when i try to compile, that's a type error, but i cant figure out whats the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to give `config` the type `Options`.

Remove the type annotation here:

```
const config: Options = {
```

so it becomes:

```
const config = {
```

It's complaining because you are casting it to `Parameters<typeof MikroORM.init>[0]`. This type includes `undefined` and `undefined` is not assignable to type `Options`.

Also I'm pretty sure in Ben Awad's tutorial he removes this type annotation and demonstrates the usage of `as` to fix another error, so make sure to rewatch that part closely. If you got questions specifically about his reddit clone, you can join his Discord server as well.

Comment: You will disable interllisense/type safety on the config by doing this, I dont see a reason why. Removing the type assertion is enough.

Comment: Using explicit type is the correct approach, with type assertions you won't be warned about not existing keys. There is no reason to use such a complex construct as `Parameters<typeof MikroORM.init>[0]` just to type an options object. There is a type for that, and it is the `Options` one.